# How to make Java run executable application?

Tags: java, windows, process, command

Code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mvn");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Output:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at com.littleHelper.app.ButtonDemo.actionPerformed(ButtonDemo.java:47)
```

But:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mvn.bat");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Run perfectly. But in cmd both run well! How to make java run like cmd?

Comment: From code clear that there is no problem with path. If were problem with path mvn.bat would not work.

Answer (score 1):

`new ProcessBuilder("mvn");` don't have an extension something like `mvn.exe` or `mvn.bat` which leads your application to read it as a folder instead.

Comment: Yes! But when type in cmd - it works without extension. The question is how to make it works like in cmd?

Comment: have you tried the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command"); instead ?

Comment: when you type mvn into cmd.exe, cmd.exe automatically tests to see if mvn.exe, mvn.cmd or mvn.bat exist on the current path.  That is a feature of cmd.exe.